# mongoid_taggable not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, tags, mongoid

I'm trying to implement the gem mongoid_taggable - [a link](https://github.com/wilkerlucio/mongoid_taggable) - which provides a simple tag system to an app with a mongoDB.

I'm implementing it the way it's adviced on github, but the tags array I get in my mongoDB is empty!

Hope you can put me on the right track:

Model -

```
class Flow
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Taggable

  attr_accessible :shot, :image, :remote_image_url

  mount_uploader :image, UserUploader

  belongs_to :user

  field :shot, :type => String
  field :remote_image_url, :type => String
end
```

View -

```
 <%= form_for @flow, :html => {:multipart => true}, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
   <fieldset>
   <legend><%= controller.action_name.capitalize %> /Form</legend>


   <p>
     <%= f.label :image %>
     <%= f.file_field :image %>
   <p/>

   <p>
     <%= f.label :tags %><br />
     <%= f.text_field :tags %>
   </p>
   <div class="form-actions">
     <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
     <%= link_to 'Cancel', users_path, :class => 'btn' %>
   </div>
   </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Database output -

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f6a13220f15ed07fb000006"), "tags_array" : [ ], "image_filename" : "_MG_2221.jpg" }
```

Comment: Please avoid to be rude because nobody answer your immediatly.

Comment: No answers usually means your title or question isn't that good.  In cases like this, you can always [edit] to improve or add detail, or (after the required waiting period) you can add a bounty.  See this [faq#bounty] section for details about the bounty.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. Have been away. I can be a bit impatient sometimes. I'll try to do better in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you don't allow mass_assignement on tags.

You have :

```
attr_accessible :shot, :image, :remote_image_url
```

But the tags is need to be assign. So do :

```
attr_accessible :shot, :image, :remote_image_url, :tags
```

Comment: You are my knight in shining armor. Thank you.